# One event handler handling the same event type but from multiple sources

Tags: events, handler

I have ten Buttons on the one form. For efficiency, I would like to have the click event from any of the ten buttons handler by the one event handler. I have Google'd extensively but cannot find a more efficient approach than the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click,Button4.Click,Button5.Click,Button6.Click,Button7.Click,Button8.Click,Button9.Click,
```

Button10.Click

Might any StackFlow subscriber know (or might conceive) of a neater means than the above please?

Sincerely,
Sean

End Sub